# Platform as a Service AWS solution to store informaton received by PHP application

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am new in the AWS Cloud services.

I am doing the learning project to better understand AWS services.

I assigned a project to prepare a new environment in the cloud, to which my team will later migrate their applications. The Stakeholders have come up with some Technical and Business requirements:

Due to the budget issue, the company cannot afford a dedicated DB engineer, so they are willing to outsource the DB management from a Cloud provider, to store and maintain the customer information received by PHP application. You must pick the right solution from AWS, which should be a Platform as a Service.It should also provide high availability, patching and back-ups. (hint: Create DB subnet group)

Which AWS Cloud service I could use to implement this requirement?

Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the Database as a Service(DaaS) options from AWS. There are plenty of choices depending on the data and its requirements. Here is a snapshot from the [official documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/):

[image]

Analyze your requirements and learn about the above choices to make an educated decision.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are looking for a relation database,

Its amazon RDS, A PaaS service provided my amazon web services. it is a highly available, scalable relational database solution service that you can setup and run in the cloud.

In regards to backups, you can enable automated daily backups and also make use of the backup retention policy to define the number of days you want to keep the backups.

Amazon RDS supports different relational databases such as mysql, postgres, oracle ,etc

#### If you are looking for a document database,

you got some options mainly DynamoDB and new DocumentDb solution.